When sending a group message to users, the Telegram PHP bot only sends it to the beginning users, and the process is repeated
I created a Telegram bot using PHP, and I saved the users' ID in user.txt, and I created a code that when the admin sends a message, the message is sent to all the users in the file, but when I send a message, the message is sent to the users at the beginning of the file, and it stops and does not send the message to all users, and continues to repeat the sending process without stopping to the users.  Who sent the message to them previously, so I can stop the bot completely by closing the webhook, and this is the code used for sending.
if ($user_id == $user_id1){

    $file = 'user.txt';

    $handle = fopen($file, 'r');

    header('Content-Type: text/plain');

    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');

    while (!feof($handle)) {

        $send_user = fgets($handle);

        sendMessage($message['text'], $send_user);

    }

    fclose($handle);}

How do I make the bot send the message to all the users in the file and not just the users at the beginning of the file? I don’t want the message to be repeated.
I added it
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

And I also added
sleep(1);

But he didn't succeed

What about the user.txt file? Are you sure the lines are seperated correctly by a newline?

Yes, I am sure, and the message is sent to the users who start successfully and fail for the rest, even though it is in the same format.

I could think of a spam protection by Telegram. Add some logging to see if the loop is executed correctly.

This also looks like a long lasting process.. HTTP ist not intended for keeping up a connection for long a time. You should close the connection as soon as possible and run the loop afterwards.

How can i do that

Here's how I do it: https://pastebin.com/esAM3GXg It closes the connection, but tells the Telegram API that all is ok, and then process the long lasting things.

What do you mean? Should I add the code on the site that I included completely inside my code?

What's that Content-Disposition: attachment header supposed to be good for?

When I attach the code that you attached to me, a warning is issued that the first line of ignore_user_abort(enable: true) is not recognized;
